# Coefficient of variance problem

Tags: time-series, statistics, data-analysis, variance, descriptive-statistics

I am doing a project and I am facing a problem I have no idea how to solve.
I have a data series of stock prices, and, based on this series I obtained another series, of so-called rentabilities (which technically are relative change indexes (Rn/R(n-1) - 1).

The thing is the following: when applying to this series the coefficient of variance I obtain the value of 123%. Has it any sense?

My series look in the following manner: most of my data (for rentabilities) is focused around the mean, which is pretty plain to see on a box-plot (leptokurtic and normal distribution), but it has A LOT of outliers, in both directions.

Then I thought about applying the index Rn/R(n-1) for the calculation of CV, and I obtain 2,3%.

The fact is, both  indexes show modification. I understand that mathematically, the standard deviation does not change, only the mean which gets translated with a unit. But, as both indexes show modification in my variable stock-prices, why should CV be so different?

Any ideas with my 123% CV? What should I do?

Comment: What is the point of that exercise?  What are you trying to answer with that cv?

Comment: Also "leptokurtic" and "normal distribution" are contradicting each other.  Since you are looking at stock returns I guess you are dealing with a heavy tail Lambert W x gaussian distribution ( similar student t).  Do you mind sharing your data then I can run it through some examples code